# Changing the size of test and train during cross validation

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I perform a regression model with 10 folds cross validation.

```
for train, test in kf.split(X, Y):
   print ("Fold ", cv)
   print("Train", X[train].shape)
   print("Test", X[test].shape)
   # define the model
   Breg = BayesianRidge(n_iter = 500, tol=0.0000000001)
   # fit the data to the model
   Breg.fit(X[train], Y[train])
   # calculate R2 for each fold and save the value into a file
   R2.append(Breg.score(X[test], Y[test]))
   # predict in test set
   ypred_test = Breg.predict(X[test])
   Y_pred_test.append(ypred_test)
   # calculate mean squared error for each fold and save into a list
   mae.append(mean_absolute_error(Y[test], ypred_test))
```

When I run the model, I observed changing in the size of training and test.

```
Fold  1
Train (14754, 9)
Test (1640, 9)
Fold  2
Train (14754, 9)
Test (1640, 9)
Fold  3
Train (14754, 9)
Test (1640, 9)
Fold  4
Train (14754, 9)
Test (1640, 9)
Fold  5
Train (14755, 9)
Test (1639, 9)
Fold  6
Train (14755, 9)
Test (1639, 9)
Fold  7
Train (14755, 9)
Test (1639, 9)
Fold  8
Train (14755, 9)
Test (1639, 9)
Fold  9
Train (14755, 9)
Test (1639, 9)
Fold  10
Train (14755, 9) 
Test (1639, 9)
```

You can see that after the fold 5 the size of training increased by 1 while the size of test decreased by 1
Any idea how this might happen and can be fixed?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) of `KFold`, which I assume is what your `kf` in `kf.split` stands for.

In the notes, it says:

> The first `n_samples % n_splits` folds have size `n_samples // n_splits + 1`, other folds have size `n_samples // n_splits`, where n_samples is the
> number of samples.

By inserting the numbers, you can see that the first 4 splits will have a size of `n_samples // n_splits + 1` and the remaining a size of `n_samples // n_splits`, so exactly a size difference of `+1`.

Comment: Thanks Kim, I read it and it mentioned that. But how I can solve it?

Comment: What do you want to solve? The reason why its being handled that way, is that you can not create 10 folds of the same size, since your n_samples % n_splits results in 4, which means its you can only divide it by 10 (10-folds) with a rest of 4. In order to then deal with these 4 remaining datapoints and to keep the difference in size of the folds small, the first four folds have one more datapoint to use up the rest of 4.

Comment: Okay, I see now what you mean. when we divide by 10, 4 is left. Thanks so much for clarification